# Center a popup window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JavaScript to open a popup window, which does work, however it is not centered, just wondered if someone can help?

```
var win = Runner.displayPopup( {
    url: "Wizard_ExternalFactors_add.php",
    width: 1400,
    height: 900,
    header: 'External Factors Wizard'
});
```

Comment: That's not a native browse popup.

Comment: What is `Runner`?

Comment: We have no idea what the source of that method does , various options available,  what css is used ,where it gets currently positioned or if the contents overflow it. If you want help you need to provide a [mcve] along with any possible documentation for `Runner`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-450px;
margin-left:-700px;
```

Comment: Adding explanation as to how this would help the OP is always appreciated. See [answer[.